# Removing a node from the middle of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am using the following code on a linked list of characters.  But whenever I run this program, I get a runtime error.

```
void ldellist(Node *head,char k) 
{
    Node *remove=head;
    Node *previous=head;
    while(remove->data!=k) 
    {
        remove=remove->next; 
    }
    while(previous->next!=remove) 
    {
        previous=previous->next; 
    }
    previous->next=remove->next;
    free(remove);
}
```

Could someone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Guys! just to make it clear, i know i am removing a character from the middle, not from the head or the tail.

Comment: what does your free(Node*) function look like?

Comment: -1 no effort, asking others to do the work, nearly all relevant info omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to do some checks?

```
void ldellist(Node *head,char k)  {
  Node *remove=head;
  Node *previous=head;
  while(remove && remove->data!=k) {
    remove=remove->next; }
  while(previous && previous->next!=remove) {
    previous=previous->next; }
  if (remove) {
    previous->next=remove->next;
    free(remove);
  } else { 
    // print some error like 'not found'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case when the node to remove is head, you'll get "remove" equals "head" and condition "previous->next!=remove" will be always true.